# Resetting back style color if clicked anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following element with onclick event that will color the clicked paragraph to red if user clicked on:-

```
 <p
    onClick={(e)=> e.currentTarget.style.color = "red"}
    >
    Click here 
    </p>

<p
    onClick={(e)=> e.currentTarget.style.color = "red"}
    >
    Another Paragraph 
    </p>

<p
    onClick={(e)=> e.currentTarget.style.color = "red"}
    >
    Another Paragraph 
    </p>
```

How can reset the color back to it original black color if user clicked else where on the page or clicked on another paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be modifying the DOM directly from a React app. Use state instead:

```
function Paragraph (props) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState();
  const style = selected ? { color: red } : undefined;

  return (
    <p {...props} style={style} />
  )
}
```

To reset it when the user clicks elsewhere, you could add an event listener to document.body while it's in the selected state. Something like this:

```
function Paragraph (props) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState();
  const style = selected ? { color: red } : undefined;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (selected) {
      // you'd probably want to check to see if the click target
      // is the current element; omitted here for simplicity
      const onClick = () => setSelected(false);

      document.body.addEventListener('click', onClick);

      // remove the listener on unmount or when selected state changes
      return () => document.body.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    }
  }, [selected])

  return (
    <p {...props} style={style} />
  )
}
```

---

Even better, use a className instead of an inline style:

```
<p {...props} className={selected ? 'selected' : ''} />
```

```css
.selected { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an eventhandler for the `<body>` element. Click events 'bubbles' up to the `<body>` if they're not cancelled. You should cancel your events, so they don't 'bubble' up to the `<body>`:

```
<p onClick={(e)=> e.currentTarget.style.color = "red"; e.stopPropagation();}>
    Click here 
</p>
```

Now just set the color of all `<p>` elements:

```
<body onClick = {() => e.target.nodeName == "DIV" && (e.target.style.color = "black");}>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach but could have unintended consequences: It's going to change everything to black regardless of whether it's the element in question.

Comment: That's actually my intention - as I understand the question.

Comment: OP wants to reset the red paragraph, not reset the entire document.

Comment: May be, then he/she needs some kind of identification, like id  or class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something else then classes. Also keep in mind this way you have event click on all elements on page, so if you need it later just expand this...
Also this can be re-written in many ways to suit the needs.

```js
const click = document.querySelectorAll(".click");
[...document.querySelectorAll('body')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.className.includes("click") === true) {
      click.forEach(p => {
        p.style.color = "black";
      })
      event.target.style.color = "red";
    } else {
      click.forEach(p => {
        p.style.color = "black";
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100% height:100%
}
```

```html
<div>test div
  <p class="click"> dont Click here
  </p>
  test div1
</div>
<p class="click"> dont Click here
</p>
<div>test div2
  <p class="click"> dont Click here
  </p>
</div>
```